# Onload JS script that redirects all links to another URL

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

I'm not a dev, but I'm really interested in JS... and I've got a question! Maybe you can help me?

Is it possible to load a JS script on a webpage that will have the following action: if the user clicks on any links of the webpage (but not on some specific links define by regex) then it redirects to a new URL defines in this same script ?

Thanks for your answers,

CH

Edit: I'd like to do it whithout any JS libraries

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can do this with any number of libraries or even with plain ole javascript. But if you're looking for someone to just write it for you, you may want to hire a freelance programmer.

Comment: Thanks Philwinkle, could you give me clue (fonction name?) to write it in plain ole JS? Is it harder to code than in using a library? Cheers

Comment: As @Baszz mentioned below, jQuery makes this easy because using `document.getElementsByTagName` doesn't have the cross-browser support that a library would for something like this. I also recommend jQuery for this, but it's certainly feasible.

Comment: Thanks for these details.But I really would like to do it in plain JS in order to avoid any conflicts between libraries. I will dig further the `document.getElementByTagName` function. I've found http://snippets.jc21.com/snippets/javascript/getelementsbytagname-cross-browse/ for cross-browser support

Answer (score 1):

Sure...maybe it's best to use a jQuery script in this situation like:

```
   $('a').click(function(){
     document.location.href = "someurl.html";
     return false;
   });
```

For your information. This script selects all links in the DOM (the $('a') part) and than tells it to execute the specified function on a click action. In this function the script tells the browser to redirect to some url. Of course you need to download and add the jQuery library from [the jQuery website](http://jquery.com/) to your webpage.

Comment: Thanks Baszz! I will check in these direction or in plain ole JS if I can! In your case, I don't need to use something like <body onload="..", do I?

Comment: Well....actually you need a wrapper function from jQuery to execute the script on page load. Place your code within this function $(document).ready(function() { ... });

Comment: Ohw...and don't forget to mark my answer as usefull or as final answer ;)